# What is the probability density function of $e^{\sigma a}b$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to figure out the probability density function of $u = e^{\sigma a} b$, where $\sigma > 0$ and $(a, b) \sim N(0, \Sigma)$
$$
\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \psi \\
\psi & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now I end up with an integral for the probability:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    & P(u < x) \\  
    &= {1 \over 2\pi \sqrt{1 - \psi^2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} da
    e^{-a^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^{e^{-a\sigma}x} db
    \exp\left[
      - {(b - a\psi)^2 \over 2(1 - \psi^2)}
    \right] \\
    &= {1 \over 2\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a^2/2}
    \text{erfc}{a\psi - e^{-a\sigma} x \over \sqrt{2(1-\psi^2)}} da
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I don't know how to evaluate the last integral or how to approximate it. Any clue? Thanks!